# Ignoring non characters in a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, character

I have written a pigLatin code and I need the code to ignore non characters i.e. I want them to stay where they are in a string. So for instance take `'1myth'`,when this is converted to piglatin I want it to be for example `1ythmway` where the number is not affected. I tried using regex but I could only get it to work for the first condition.
Here is my code below:

```
import re
Vowels =("aeiouAEIOU")
y = input("\n Enter sentence ")
x = y.split()
for word in x:
 a =re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '',word);
    
 if a[0] in Vowels:
      word +='hay'
                
 elif all(char not in Vowels for char in word):
          word = word[1:] + word[0]                                                                                                                          
          word += 'way' 
              
 elif word[0] not in Vowels:
          for i, j in enumerate(word):
              if j in Vowels:break
          word = word[i:] + word[:i]
          word += 'ay'
               
          print(word, end = ' ')
```

Comment: use and google `.isdigit()` and `isalpha()`

Comment: There are no "non characters" in a string. I think you mean non-letters.

Comment: ah yeah I mean non-letters

Answer (score 0):

you can place a try-except condition like below:(This is only example.Implement it according to your condition)

```
    words = '1myth'
w = list(words)
for i in w:
    try:
        if type(int(i)) is int:
            pass
    except:
        print(i) //You can write your character trasforming conditions here.
```

This way you can ignore all non-characters.I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the try-except condition but it still move non characters

Comment: The print(i) statement above(in the except) gives the output as [m,y,t,h]. So, it removed 1.

Answer (score 0):

Easier method to ignore digits is by using isdigit () as Patrick suggested.  Here I'm replacing all the characters to "n" to show the digit is unchanged.

```
>>> word = '2math'
>>> new_word = ''
>>> for char in word:
...     if char.isdigit ():
...         new_word += char
...     else:
...         new_word += char.replace(char, 'n')
... 
>>> new_word
'2nnnn'
```